# Is this question appropriate for the Programmers Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Is this question appropriate for the Programmers Stack Exchange site?  If not, is there a Stack Exchange site frequented by folks in the software industry where this question would be appropriate?

> What is a good solution for producing a software product documentation
>   site?
>
> We have a commercial, "off the shelf", SAAS application that needs
>   documentation and we want to produce the documentation in such a way
>   that it's accessible online for our customers, our QA team, and other
>   internal staff.  It should be easy for non-technical people to
>   add/maintain content including pictures.  Doesn't necessarily need to
>   be free or self-hosted.
>
> Was thinking about using a wiki but wasn't sure if there was a better
>   solution.

Comment: questions like this feel troublesome: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important "see: 'Why is research important?'").** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2):

The question is appropriate for Programmers, but needs a bit of work to make it answerable, as indicated by the comment from @gnat.